# Estimating the difference between heads and tails when tossing N coins

Tags: probability

I have this problem:
Let $Z_{n}$ = (H-T) be the random variable which is equal to the number of heads
minus the number of tails after tossing n coins. Show that $\forall \varepsilon >0$ we have that $$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P( \vert Z_{n} \vert > n^{1/2+ \varepsilon}) = 0$$
**What I've tried:**

First of all: I'm not sure what it means to show that the probability of a number being greater than other is cero.

So, what I understand I have to show is:
$$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P( \vert Z_{n} \vert = k) = 0 , \forall \varepsilon >0: \forall k: n \geq k > n^{1/2 + \varepsilon}$$
Therefore, I started something like this:

Let $k$ be a integer and $\varepsilon >0$ such that $n \geq k > n^{1/2 + \varepsilon}$. Since $Z_{n}$ is binomially distributed, we know that $$ P(Z_{n}=k)=  {n\choose k}\frac{1}{2^{n}} $$
Now, for a estimation of $ {n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ we can use Stirling formula:
$$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{e^{-n}n^{n}(2\pi n)^{1/2}} = 1 $$
And apply it for every term in $ n \choose k$.
But this approach ends with a horrible limit that I can't calculate but I know is less than 1.

Other approach was: I know that ${n \choose k }$ reaches it maximum when $k = \frac{n}{2}$. And I was able to show that $$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {n\choose \frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{2^{n}} = 0$$
But this doesn't depends on $\varepsilon$ so maybe something is wrong.
The last approach that I've tried was: Try to prove by induction that for every $ \varepsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ with $n \geq 2$. The statement holds for every integer $k$ such that $  n^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}}  \leq k \leq n^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}}$.
And this was the worst idea.
...Please, I need help to solve this problem :(

Comment: What might be an easier way to think about this is as follows: Prove that $$P(|Z_n| > n^{1/2+\epsilon}) = f(n)$$ for some decreasing function $f(n)$ (for example $\frac 1n$), all for a fixed $\epsilon$. Also, could you please give some pointers as to the difficulty level that the answer should be at. This is fairly easy to prove using Chernoff Bounds, but if you have not learned that yet, that won't be a particularly helpful answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. The difficulty level is: first course in probability theory for second year undergraduate students. I never heard before about Chernoff Bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first approximate $Z_n$ by a normal distribution:
$$Z_n=2\operatorname{Binom}(n,0.5)-n\approx2\mathcal N(0.5n,0.25n)-n=\mathcal N(n,n)-n=\mathcal N(0,n)$$
where the second parameter of $\mathcal N$ denotes variance, so it has standard deviation $\sqrt n$. Then
$$P(|Z_n|>n^{1/2+\varepsilon})\approx P(|\mathcal N(0,n)|>n^{1/2+\varepsilon})=P(|\mathcal N(0,1)|>n^\varepsilon)$$
and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\varepsilon=\infty$, the limit of $P(|Z_n|>n^{1/2+\varepsilon})$ is 0.

Comment: Isn't $2\mathcal{N}(0.5n, 0.25n)-n=\mathcal{N}(n,0.5n)-n$ instead of $2\mathcal{N}(0.5n, 0.25n)-n=\mathcal{N}(n,n)-n$?

Comment: @JuanDiegoChavesSanguino You missed it; the variance multiplies by $2^2$ upon multiplying by two, not 2.